# set the location of all open forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

this code lets me set the location of the `form` each time I drag my map.

```
Private Sub map_OnMapDrag() Handles map.OnMapDrag
    If f2c1.Visible Then
        f2c1.Location = camera1.LocalPosition + New Point(20, -240)
    End If
    If f2c2.Visible Then
        f2c2.Location = camera2.LocalPosition + New Point(20, -240)
    End If
    If f2c3.Visible Then
        f2c3.Location = camera3.LocalPosition + New Point(20, -240)
    End If
End Sub
```

however, I want it on a public sub..

and this code, which I think gets **all** the **visible** `forms` ..

```
Dim forms = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of frmCamera)()
    While forms.Count > 0
        forms(forms.Count - 1).Visible = True
    End While
```

how can I make it so that all **visible** forms gets their location everytime I drag it, so that even if I dynamically added another `form` it won't be a problem. that's my goal.

can you guys fix this for me..

```
Dim forms = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of frmCamera)()
    While forms.Count > 0
        forms(forms.Count - 1).Visible = True
    End While
    forms.Location = 'location that I want
```

Comment: Please don’t compare against `True`. It’s just `If f2c1.Visible Then …`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim forms As Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of frmMain) = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of frmMain).Where(Function(frm) frm.Visible)

For Each f As Form In forms
    f.Location = New Point(0, 0) ' set coordinate as needed
Next
```

Comment: This throws an InvalidCastException when I run it. If you remove the `As FormCollection` it works.

Comment: I was going to post the error, nice move @endofzero.. but I have another question @adventure, what if each of the `forms` have different location? as seen on the first code of my question, they are tagged to 3 different `camera` or should I call marker.

Comment: Thanks -- My bad. I forgot the Linq functions return a  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable (Of TResult). Sounds like you have Option Infer turned on; I prefer leaving it off.

Comment: @AdorableVB, what is Camera? And is there a collection of them? And if so, you'll need a means of knowing the relationship between each instance of the Camera collection and forms collection.

Comment: @Adventure `camera1` `camera2` are markers of a gmap control from [link](http://codeplex.com).. I am going to ask another question.. a minute.

Comment: what's the difference between your first answer and the edited one? also, this is my new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393339/how-to-separate-visible-form-instances-locations)

Comment: I edited the type expected to be returned by the right side of the assignment. Originally I was thinking the right side returns a FormCollection. Well, that's the type that the OpenForms function returns. But the Linq functions (OfType and Where) return an IEnumerable(Of T).