# how to separate visible form instances' locations

Tags: vb.net, winforms

from a question here : [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390691/set-the-location-of-all-open-forms/20392097?noredirect=1#comment30450286_20392097)

```
Dim forms As Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of frmMain) = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of frmMain).Where(Function(frm) frm.Visible)

For Each f As Form In forms
f.Location = New Point(0, 0) ' set coordinate as needed
Next
```

**UPDATE** the above code gets all visible `forms` but since its generic, all the visible `forms` appear on one place..

let's say, I have 3 markers.. named `camera1` `camera2` `camera3`..
on `Form_Load` I will click those 3 markers, and a supposed video feed will appear (in this case, each with a new instance of `form2`)

this is my code in which does what I want, only problem is, I want it to be reusable for the future of dynamically adding more rather than this, predefined.

```
Dim f2c1 As New Form2
Dim f2c2 As New Form2
Dim f2c3 As New Form2
    If f2c1.Visible = True Then
        f2c1.Location = camera1.LocalPosition + New Point(20, -240)
    End If
    If f2c2.Visible = True Then
        f2c2.Location = camera2.LocalPosition + New Point(20, -240)
    End If
    If f2c3.Visible = True Then
        f2c3.Location = camera3.LocalPosition + New Point(20, -240)
    End If
```

that code, is this.. If I click the marker, drag the map. video feed `form2` stays with them.

[image]

I want it on a `function` or `sub` that will do this..

```
'Public Sub when I drag the map()
'every form visible
'will follow -- let's say, will follow what marker clicked them
```

ask me if you need anything.. thanks

Comment: See... since yesterday I have been involved in various questions (attitudes) which I don't consider that do belong here. I am also not a good helper there because I don't think that should be patient with some behaviours. Honestly, not too much time to deal with you to make sure about this but, just in case, and in order to avoid a long, tiring experience for both of us; I will better delete my answer. You have got all the information you need (= you can store anything you need in Tag and, no, it does not affect the performance at all), hope that will help you.

Comment: Not exactly clear why you think that using a Form is a good idea.  If you use, say, a Panel or UserControl instead then they'll automatically move since they are child controls.  Getting a Form to move requires subscribing the LocationChanged event of the form that displays the map.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll try to use UserControl

varocarbas I see, maybe downgrading to 3.5 Client version made it laggy than usual

Answer (score 0):

I did some workaround

```
Dim mList As New List(Of String)



marker.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.Always   'as an indetifier of each markers as
marker.ToolTipText = dtrow("MarkerName")        'I have added it to a for each

Try

        For Each m In mList                     'get items from the list
            If item.ToolTipText = m Then        'check same name
                Dim f As New Form2
                With f
                    If .Visible = True Then
                        .Hide()
                    Else
                        .Show()
                        Dim p As New Point
                        p = item.LocalPosition + New Point(20, -240)
                        .Location = p              'after I click form will appear right next to them
                        .Text = m
                    End If
                End With
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

this is still not the ideal thing that is on my mind, but this practically answers my question for the moment.